# Should Spring DAO classes refer only one object of the model?

Tags: spring, hibernate, design-patterns, dao, one-to-one

I am very new of Spring, I will straight to the point. The layers in my application seem to be rather conventional:

```
- Controller
- DTO
- Service    
- DAO
- Model
```

Generally speaking, should every implementation of a DAO interface deal with only one object from the model? (sorry I can find only trivial examples which really don't face this point)
Likely sometime in one-to-one relationship, bidirectional, say with only one shared primary key. Hibernate doesn't care, apart from mapping, it can't handle POJO references to each other. Say there is this situation i.e.:

```
Table1: Parent        Table2: Child
------------------    ----------------------
| PARENT_ID (PK) |<---|CHILD_ID (PK and FK)|
------------------    ----------------------
```

it will require to maintain updated respectively:

```
parent.setChild(a_child); // private field of Parent.java
child.setParent(a_parent); // private field of Child.java
```

Where is - looking at the mentioned layers - the right place for implementing this kind of logic? If Hibernate looks after the mapping between model's objects and DB, who should be the one taking care of the coherence between POJO objects of the model?

My headline question wonders if DAOs can deal with several POJOs from the model, DAOs can also keep those POJOs coherence on.

Many thanks 
Bye

Comment: And why bother with typical layers at all? Check out Hexagonal Architecture (http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture, http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/10/exploring-hexagonal-architecture) which is closely related to DDD. Once you have your project organised with respect to the business responsibilities (not layers) the whole project is easier to read and reason about.

Comment: I would say this has not so much to do with Hibernate nor Spring but is more a architectural question. And the question in its current state would only yield opinionated answers.

Comment: R4J thanks, I'll take a look. Deinum thanks, I added design-pattern tag. I am asking what usually is the "common practice" into Spring MVC Web Application to handle that sort of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAOs should be designed with only one main thing in mind - **Business responsibility**.

**For example:**

```
 AccountService <-->      AccountsDAO
                     |        |           |
            AccountsModel ClientModel BalanceModel
```

You cannot limit your DAO to just one model. The DAO is supposed to perform what it can provide to support your service layer.

Your hibernate/ORM models with handle only the relationship between tables and they wouldn't have idea on what invocation the Service layer expects.

**End word** : DAOs can interact with many Models/POJOs if the DAOs is designed for it's very own purpose.

Comment: "You cannot limit your DAO to just one model." .. you can if you want to, there's nothing to stop you

Comment: Ofcourse yes. The DAO is supposed to perform what it can provide to support your service layer. @blank. I don't mean that not to use. I meant to say that don't limit. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Oh thank you very much indeed. So I understand you can actually have got one DAO's class which refers two objects from the model if this is included inside the **Business responsability**. Then I could have: **Model1andModel2DAO.java**, is that possible?

Comment: @desmogix Your DAO should be named based on responsibility, that gives clarity of what it should do. You don't need to worry about Models in it's naming. It can be free from it as well :)